# Register address offset of a 16-bit register

Tags: microcontroller, sensor

I was reading a document and they said the address of the SAVE register is 0x00 and the address of the CALSW is 0x01. However, each register is 16-bit wide, so the address of the CALSW register must be 0x02, right? In fact, they use the register address 0x01 to calibrate this sensor. This is the [SINDT sensor](https://www.wit-motion.com/professional-tilt-switch/witmotion-sindt-rs485-imu-2-axis.html) from WITMOTION. I'm really quite confused, maybe I missed some basic knowledge. Below is some information contained in the [datasheet](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81WX18FfpsL.pdf)(Chapter 5.1):

[image]

Comment: @Velvel Thanks, datasheet link updated

Comment: Your reasoning is roughly akin to claiming that you can't have house numbers 1001 and 1002 on the same street because a house is more than 1 meter wide.  An address is an identifier that means whatever all parties to the communication agree that it means, and doesn't have to have a physical interpretation.

Comment: Thanks for linking the correct datasheet. Chapter 5.2 contains lots of useful information, including good examples.

Comment: @BenVoigt this intuition makes perfect sense when we consider the typical layout of MMIO registers in CPUs and MCUs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps a more intuitive way to understand this is if you look at it as an array.

```c
uint16_t register[0x0B];

#define REG_ADDR_SAVE     0x00
#define REG_ADDR_CALSW    0x01
#define REG_ADDR_RSW      0x02
..
#define REG_ADDR_GZOFFSET 0x0A
```

The address (16-bit) is the index, and the register data (16-bit) is the indexed entry.

For example, with `register[REG_ADDR_CALSW]` you can access the `CALSW` register.

Comment: @greybeard Now that the correct [datasheet](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81WX18FfpsL.pdf) has been linked, the address is indeed 16-bit (chapter 5.2). Thanks and updated.

Answer (score 4):

No it reads right there, each address has a word of data that is 16 bits. It means the data is not addressable in 8-bit bytes.